# Visual Studio Code Incorrectly Highlights Errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, tsx

I've just began developing using React & Next.js and more, and I'm using a website template which runs perfectly fine, I see my results and everything functions. Meanwhile, in the editor, I get a variety of errors on code that functions perfectly.

**Errors**:

`JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.ts(7026)`

`Cannot find module '@heroicons/react/24/outline' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

`Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

[image: code being highlighted]

I've tried to problem solve, I've installed ESLint and TypeScript, I've tried messing around with my `tsconfig` which didn't do much good, I've updated to the newest version, and I simply can't get it to accept that this code works. How do I get it to properly handle this code?